# brew update failure while executing git checkout

Tags: homebrew

After an interrupted `brew update` because of a network issue, Homebrew appears to be broken:

```
$ brew update
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master
```

Looking at the `/usr/local` Git repository, there's no remote repository.

```
$ cd `brew --prefix`
$ git remote -v
$
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Fixed with the following commands:

```
$ cd `brew --prefix`
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: I got 403s from github with the https URL for the repo.  This worked for me:

$ git remote add origin git://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git

Comment: `brew update` never works first time. There's always issues with the working tree.

Comment: I'm currently getting the following, possibly from a Github DDOS: `/usr/local at owne-pc (master ✔)% brew update`
`error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation timed out while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs`
`fatal: HTTP request failed`
`Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: for whatever reason, some of my files were owned by root. Must have used sudo at some point.  I chown'd the files to my regular user and followed these instructions and it worked great.

Comment: I had to run `git clean -f` after running `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Answer (score 3):

when i try it, sudo is needed:

```
$ git reset --hard origin/master
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/macos/xcode.rb' (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
$ sudo !!
sudo git reset --hard origin/master
Password:
HEAD is now at 97302bf xrootd 3.2.2
```

Comment: You should check your permissions. Homebrew is designed to work *without* `sudo`. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had just upgraded to OS X El Capitan and none of the other solutions worked.

I took note of the packages in /usr/local/Cellar and then deleted the Cellar folder and started with a fresh install.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install )"
```

Then I brew installed the packages again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where from /usr/local (== $(brew --prefix)) I tried the answer by @
Julien Carsique but still got the error:

```
[local]master$ git checkout 3115d85 hdf5.rb
error: pathspec '3115d85' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'hdf5.rb' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

This was because I the hdf5 routine was in /usr/local/Library/tab/homebrew-science which has it's own git repository. To fix this I entered:

```
[local]master$ cd Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/
[homebrew-science]master$ git checkout 3115d85 hdf5.rb
```

Now I can install a previous version of the desired library (e.g. hdf5)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

What solved Homebrew git errors for me was simply to `cd ~` and run `brew update` in my home directory. The command failed when I was in a folder shared on GitHub. Also, `clang` magically appeared again from `brew config` after `cd ~`.