# Error installing Homebrew on a fresh Mavericks install

Tags: ruby, terminal, homebrew, osx-mavericks, permission-denied

Did a fresh install of **Mavericks** from a clean disk, installing **Homebrew** before updating my Ruby versions with rbenv. Getting this error:

```
error: unable to create file bin/brew (Permission denied)
error: unable to create file share/man/man1/brew.1 (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Are you installing homebrew for the first time using: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: Also ensure you have xcode and the command line tools installed.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370552/brew-update-failure-while-executing-git-checkout

Comment: @Lukas no I used the link at the bottom of this page - http://brew.sh and yeah I've got xcode and the command line tools installed.

Comment: What is your current version of Ruby? run `ruby -v` and paste somewhere here. Should be 2.0. May be something wrong with the location it's trying to add it to. Surprised brew doesn't account for that already though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you *can* do to fix, some of which I don't really recommend as they change permissions of folder and could eventually lead to other issues.

1. Run as superuser: `sudo ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
   https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

   That should force it to run, but may give it the wrong permissions.
2. Ensure there are no other competing installs of homebrew. Check `/usr/local` for a directory called `Cellar`. Also ensure there aren't any existing scripts either in the `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/share/man/man1/` directories. A quick sanity check is to run `which brew` and see if it returns a location. If any of those do exist, remove and try to reinstall.
3. Change the permissions of the `/usr/local` directory. I've done this for npm before but it's mostly bad idea as the rest of the system may depend on what those permissions are without warning. To do this, run the following command, probably as the superuser (using sudo):

   `chown $USER -r /usr/local/`

Comment: I got it figured, not totally sure how though. I followed this guys post http://matthewcarriere.com/2013/08/05/how-to-install-and-use-homebrew/ rather then the Homebrew homepage. Don't know why it was an issue but it works now.